# Sails js and Heroku : An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served.

Tags: heroku, sails.js

I need help with heroku. My app works perfectly, but today is not working. I didnt modify any file. Somebody can help me? I followed another post in stackOverFlow, but doesnt work.

I run heroku logs:

```
 2017-02-21T14:51:12.588970+00:00 app[web.1]: Line 3997 in .tmp/public/concat/production.js
2017-02-21T14:51:12.588971+00:00 app[web.1]:  
2017-02-21T14:51:12.588971+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-02-21T14:51:12.589061+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-21T14:51:12.589124+00:00 app[web.1]: Looks like a Grunt error occurred--
2017-02-21T14:51:12.589185+00:00 app[web.1]: Please fix it, then **restart Sails** to continue running tasks (e.g. watching for changes in assets)
2017-02-21T14:51:12.589241+00:00 app[web.1]: Or if you're stuck, check out the troubleshooting tips below.
2017-02-21T14:51:12.589303+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-21T14:51:12.589958+00:00 app[web.1]: Troubleshooting tips:
2017-02-21T14:51:12.590030+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-21T14:51:12.590089+00:00 app[web.1]:  *-> Are "grunt" and related grunt task modules installed locally?  Run `npm install` if you're not sure.
2017-02-21T14:51:12.590133+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-21T14:51:12.590178+00:00 app[web.1]:  *-> You might have a malformed LESS, SASS, CoffeeScript file, etc.
2017-02-21T14:51:12.590247+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-21T14:51:12.590287+00:00 app[web.1]:  *-> Or maybe you don't have permissions to access the `.tmp` directory?
2017-02-21T14:51:12.590377+00:00 app[web.1]:      e.g., `/app/.tmp` ?
2017-02-21T14:51:12.590423+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-21T14:51:12.590468+00:00 app[web.1]:      If you think this might be the case, try running:
2017-02-21T14:51:12.592153+00:00 app[web.1]:      sudo chown -R 17728 /app/.tmp
2017-02-21T14:51:12.592214+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-21T14:51:30.670658+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: The hook `grunt` is taking too long to load.
2017-02-21T14:51:30.670679+00:00 app[web.1]: Make sure it is triggering its `initialize()` callback, or else set `sails.config.grunt._hookTimeout to a higher value (currently 20000)
2017-02-21T14:51:30.670680+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Timeout.tooLong [as _onTimeout] (/app/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/loadHooks.js:85:21)
2017-02-21T14:51:30.670682+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
2017-02-21T14:51:30.670682+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
2017-02-21T14:51:30.670683+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
2017-02-21T14:51:30.780591+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-02-21T14:51:30.795109+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-02-21T14:51:30.796348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-02-21T14:51:33.992516+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-02-21T14:51:36.040206+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-21T14:51:36.040223+00:00 app[web.1]: > estudioMate@0.0.0 start /app
2017-02-21T14:51:36.040224+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2017-02-21T14:51:36.040225+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-21T14:51:37.483529+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2017-02-21T14:51:37.483541+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2017-02-21T14:51:37.483542+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2017-02-21T14:51:37.602636+00:00 app[web.1]: Express midleware for passport
2017-02-21T14:51:37.621476+00:00 app[web.1]: Tue, 21 Feb 2017 14:51:37 GMT connect deprecated multipart: use parser (multiparty, busboy, formidable) npm module instead at 
node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:56:20
2017-02-21T14:51:37.621689+00:00 app[web.1]: Tue, 21 Feb 2017 14:51:37 GMT connect deprecated limit: Restrict request size at location of read at node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/multipart.js:86:15
2017-02-21T14:51:37.656950+00:00 app[web.1]: The default `sails-disk` adapter is not designed for use as a production database;
2017-02-21T14:51:37.657085+00:00 app[web.1]: Instead, please use another adapter; e.g. sails-postgresql or sails-mongo.
2017-02-21T14:51:37.657042+00:00 app[web.1]: (it stores the entire contents of your database in memory)
2017-02-21T14:51:37.657116+00:00 app[web.1]: For more info, see: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/deployment
2017-02-21T14:51:37.657131+00:00 app[web.1]: To hide this warning message, enable `sails.config.orm.skipProductionWarnings`.
2017-02-21T14:51:37.657481+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-21T14:51:37.657506+00:00 app[web.1]: A project-wide `sails.config.models.migrate` setting has not been configured for this app.
2017-02-21T14:51:37.657550+00:00 app[web.1]: Since the NODE_ENV env variable is set to "production", auto-migration will be disabled automatically.
2017-02-21T14:51:37.657575+00:00 app[web.1]: (i.e. `migrate: 'safe'`)
2017-02-21T14:51:39.409768+00:00 app[web.1]: ** Grunt :: An error occurred. **
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410163+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410166+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410167+00:00 app[web.1]: Aborted due to warnings.
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410168+00:00 app[web.1]: Running "uglify:dist" (uglify) task
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410168+00:00 app[web.1]: JS_Parse_Error {
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410169+00:00 app[web.1]:   message: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token punc «}», expected punc «:»',
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410170+00:00 app[web.1]:   filename: '../concat/production.js',
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410171+00:00 app[web.1]:   line: 3997,
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410171+00:00 app[web.1]:   col: 31,
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410172+00:00 app[web.1]:   pos: 284354,
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410187+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Uglifying source .tmp/public/concat/production.js failed.
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410183+00:00 app[web.1]:   stack: 'Error\n  at new JS_Parse_Error (<anonymous>:1534:18)\n  at js_error (<anonymous>:1542:11)\n  at croak (<anonymous>:2089:9)\n  at token_error (<anonymous>:2097:9)\n  at expect_token (<anonymous>:2110:9)\n  at expect (<anonymous>:2113:36)\n  at eval (<anonymous>:2686:13)\n  at eval (<anonymous>:2136:24)\n  at expr_atom (<anonymous>:2616:35)\n  at maybe_unary (<anonymous>:2792:19)\n  at expr_ops (<anonymous>:2827:24)\n  at maybe_conditional (<anonymous>:2832:20)\n  at maybe_assign (<anonymous>:2856:20)\n  at expression (<anonymous>:2875:20)\n  at expr_list (<anonymous>:2641:24)\n  at subscripts (<anonymous>:2775:30)\n  at subscripts (<anonymous>:2752:20)\n  at expr_atom (<anonymous>:2628:20)\n  at maybe_unary (<anonymous>:2792:19)\n  at expr_ops (<anonymous>:2827:24)\n  at maybe_conditional (<anonymous>:2832:20)\n  at maybe_assign (<anonymous>:2856:20)\n  at expression (<anonymous>:2875:20)\n  at simple_statement (<anonymous>:2314:55)\n  at eval (<anonymous>:2183:19)\n  at eval (<anonymous>:2136:24)\n  at block_ (<anonymous>:2429:20)\n  at eval (<anonymous>:2401:25)\n  at function_ (<anonymous>:2407:15)\n  at expr_atom (<anonymous>:2622:24)\n  at maybe_unary (<anonymous>:2792:19)\n  at expr_ops (<anonymous>:2827:24)\n  at maybe_conditional (<anonymous>:2832:20)\n  at maybe_assign (<anonymous>:2856:20)\n  at maybe_assign (<anonymous>:2864:32)\n  at expression (<anonymous>:2875:20)\n  at simple_statement (<anonymous>:2314:55)\n  at eval (<anonymous>:2183:19)\n  at eval (<anonymous>:2136:24)\n  at block_ (<anonymous>:2429:20)\n  at eval (<anonymous>:2401:25)\n  at function_ (<anonymous>:2407:15)\n  at expr_atom (<anonymous>:2622:24)\n  at maybe_unary (<anonymous>:2792:19)\n  at expr_ops (<anonymous>:2827:24)\n  at maybe_conditional (<anonymous>:2832:20)\n  at maybe_assign (<anonymous>:2856:20)\n  at expression (<anonymous>:2875:20)\n  at expr_list (<anonymous>:2641:24)\n  at eval (<anonymous>:2651:23)\n  at eval (<anonymous>:2136:24)\n  at expr_atom (<anonymous>:2614:35)\n  at maybe_unary (<anonymous>:2792:19)\n  at expr_ops (<anonymous>:2827:24)\n  at maybe_conditional (<anonymous>:2832:20)\n  at maybe_assign (<anonymous>:2856:20)\n  at expression (<anonymous>:2875:20)\n  at expr_list (<anonymous>:2641:24)\n  at subscripts (<anonymous>:2775:30)\n  at subscripts (<anonymous>:2752:20)\n  at subscripts (<anonymous>:2772:20)\n  at subscripts (<anonymous>:2752:20)\n  at expr_atom (<anonymous>:2628:20)\n  at maybe_unary (<anonymous>:2792:19)\n  at expr_ops (<anonymous>:2827:24)\n  at maybe_conditional (<anonymous>:2832:20)\n  at maybe_assign (<anonymous>:2856:20)\n  at expression (<anonymous>:2875:20)\n  at simple_statement (<anonymous>:2314:55)\n  at eval (<anonymous>:2183:19)\n  at eval (<anonymous>:2136:24)\n  at eval (<anonymous>:2904:23)\n  at Object.parse (<anonymous>:2915:7)\n  at /app/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/tasks/lib/uglify.js:54:27\n  at Array.forEach (native)\n  at Object.exports.minify (/app/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/tasks/lib/uglify.js:37:11)\n  at /app/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/tasks/uglify.js:156:25\n  at Array.forEach (native)\n  at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/tasks/uglify.js:77:16)\n  at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:255:15)\n  at Object.thisTask.fn (/app/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:73:16)\n  at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:294:30)\n  at Task.runTaskFn (/app/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:244:24)\n  at Task.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:293:12)\n  at /app/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:220:11\n  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)\n  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)\n' }
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410187+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: Uglification failed.
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410188+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token punc «}», expected punc «:». 
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410189+00:00 app[web.1]: Line 3997 in .tmp/public/concat/production.js
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410189+00:00 app[web.1]:  
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410190+00:00 app[web.1]: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410287+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410347+00:00 app[web.1]: Looks like a Grunt error occurred--
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410405+00:00 app[web.1]: Please fix it, then **restart Sails** to continue running tasks (e.g. watching for changes in assets)
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410465+00:00 app[web.1]: Or if you're stuck, check out the troubleshooting tips below.
2017-02-21T14:51:39.410527+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-21T14:51:39.411169+00:00 app[web.1]: Troubleshooting tips:
2017-02-21T14:51:39.411248+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-21T14:51:39.411309+00:00 app[web.1]:  *-> Are "grunt" and related grunt task modules installed locally?  Run `npm install` if you're not sure.
2017-02-21T14:51:39.411377+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-21T14:51:39.411435+00:00 app[web.1]:  *-> You might have a malformed LESS, SASS, CoffeeScript file, etc.
2017-02-21T14:51:39.411489+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-21T14:51:39.411544+00:00 app[web.1]:  *-> Or maybe you don't have permissions to access the `.tmp` directory?
2017-02-21T14:51:39.411755+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-21T14:51:39.411678+00:00 app[web.1]:      e.g., `/app/.tmp` ?
2017-02-21T14:51:39.411812+00:00 app[web.1]:      If you think this might be the case, try running:
2017-02-21T14:51:39.413647+00:00 app[web.1]:      sudo chown -R 59060 /app/.tmp
2017-02-21T14:51:39.413728+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-21T14:51:57.381050+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: The hook `grunt` is taking too long to load.
2017-02-21T14:51:57.381063+00:00 app[web.1]: Make sure it is triggering its `initialize()` callback, or else set `sails.config.grunt._hookTimeout to a higher value (currently 20000)
2017-02-21T14:51:57.381064+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Timeout.tooLong [as _onTimeout] (/app/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/loadHooks.js:85:21)
2017-02-21T14:51:57.381066+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
2017-02-21T14:51:57.381066+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
2017-02-21T14:51:57.381067+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
2017-02-21T14:51:57.570097+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-02-21T14:51:57.553867+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-02-21T14:51:58.636986+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.equipomate.com request_id=c24795a8-27d7-490a-87e3-63217a2dce6c fwd="186.153.254.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-21T14:51:58.812104+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.equipomate.com request_id=026d9527-41f1-4124-816b-d1a1b5735b4b fwd="186.153.254.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-21T14:52:35.751663+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.equipomate.com request_id=d0e1a421-a1ad-4e01-bd95-32cee5e79dcb fwd="186.153.254.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-21T14:52:48.270115+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.equipomate.com request_id=e60095d6-0a4c-4e8f-9ed9-04667531ce65 fwd="186.153.254.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-21T14:53:59.766514+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.equipomate.com request_id=ba41e862-7e49-4a77-b943-2922b1787660 fwd="186.153.254.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-21T14:56:37.383946+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.equipomate.com request_id=8c14b2fa-fde5-428c-a6c3-0bb9690613d9 fwd="186.153.254.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-21T14:58:54.174763+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.equipomate.com request_id=273424e6-5eaa-4685-af19-5f8859466e3f fwd="186.153.254.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-21T14:59:15.578510+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.equipomate.com request_id=b326c9f4-8552-4934-94c4-db22d0c6d4fa fwd="186.153.254.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-21T14:59:17.342443+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.equipomate.com request_id=616ce76b-5753-461d-a520-01a2593efc75 fwd="186.153.254.79" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I run npm install, and git heroku push again but doesnt happen.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean your app was running fine on Heroku and now it just stopped? Or are you saying that you can run your app locally, but when you push to Heroku it doesn't work?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer me. My app runs locally but when I push to HEroku doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to do a little more work to prepare sails to run on Heroku. First, there's a build process inherent in Sails. When you push to Heroku by default the `NODE_ENV` environment variable is set to `production`. That will cause `npm` to not load any of your development dependencies. The quickest fix to see if that's the only error (And I'm not sure it is) is to set your `NODE_ENV` env variable to `staging` (or anything else really, as long as it's not `production`) and try to push again. That should load your dev dependencies, and may get you further.

Ultimately if you're going to serve Sails on Heroku, you'll need to figure out a better way to deploy. I'd suggest checking out this `heroku-sails` example and package: https://github.com/chadn/heroku-sails

Answer (score 0):

When I deploy a sails.js app to heroku I typically do the following at a minimum -

1. in your .sailsrc file - you need to turn off grunt (when doing local dev, comment this out)-

   {"generators": {"modules": {}},"hooks": {"grunt": false}}
2. You will then want to configure your static assets to load from a compiled directory when the NODE_ENV is prod, so in /config/env/production.js - add a variable to your exports for -

   paths:{public:__dirname+'/../../www/'}
3. Add that www folder in your project root and run the command 'grunt build' or 'grunt buildProd'.  This will then precompile all your assets for heroku since grunt can take a long time to load/run and can keep your application from starting.

There may be some other things you want to do such as ensure your site is setup to use redis or some type of db for sockets and sessions.  You may also want to use something like pm2 to actually load your app as if you are on a larger dyno you can then run multiple instances of your sails app on the same dyno.

Checkout http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/deployment/hosting#?deploying-to-heroku for some more info direct from Sails.js